# Backbone.JS design pattern to fetch collections in order

Tags: backbone.js

I have several collections to be fetched on page load. Every collection depends on the previously loaded collection so I need to fetch them in order. This doesn't seem to be the right way to do it:

```
groupCollection.fetch({
    success: function() {
        userCollection.fetch({
            success: function() {
                itemCollection.fetch();    
            }
        })
    }
});
```

Is there a design pattern for this or am I taking a wrong approach from the beginning?

Comment: It may be the wrong approach as your blocking Javascript execution, the best way i see is to group all your ajax requests into one (if possible)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is an option to listen to `reset` event on parent collection, and load nested collection.

```
groupCollection.on("reset", function() {
  userCollection.fetch();
});

userCollection.on("reset", function() {
  itemCollection.fetch(); 
});

groupCollection.fetch();
```